# Airbrake throwing error "pybrake - ERROR - strconv.ParseInt: parsing "None": invalid syntax"

Tags: python, django, go, logging, airbrake

I'm trying to use the Airbrake logger in a Django project following the steps described in https://github.com/airbrake/pybrake#django-integration.

I've configured my `LOGGING` setting like so:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'airbrake': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'pybrake.LoggingHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'lucy_web': {
            'handlers': ['airbrake'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in a particular file in the `lucy_web` hierarchy called `lucy_web/lib/session_recommendation.py`, I have the following test function:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def log_something():
    logger.error("Logging something...")
```

However, if I try to call this function from the Django shell, `pybrake` itself logs an error:

> strconv.ParseInt: parsing "None": invalid syntax

Here is the full sequence of commands:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro-2:lucy-web kurtpeek$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.3.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from lucy_web.lib.session_recommendation import *

In [2]: log_something()

In [3]: 2018-05-30 17:25:32,201 - pybrake - ERROR - strconv.ParseInt: parsing "None": invalid syntax
```

It would appear from https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt that `strconv.ParseInt` is actually a built-in function of the Go language, so I don't understand why `pybrake`, which is a Python package, is throwing this error, or how to debug it. Can anyone explain this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems airbrake server itself is written in Go.

This can be inferred from the following facts:

- In their "About" page (https://airbrake.io/about) they list one of their members as their "Lead Go developer" and say they've been "using Go since before 1.0". Also in their CTO description they say he likes "hacking his home with Go".
- You are getting a `strconv.ParseInt` (Go) error from Python
- There is a report of getting also a `strconv.ParseInt` from using a Ruby client to report airbrake errors (https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/issues/502)

So explanation for the error would be that the Python client is getting this error from the server when sending the report, and logging this.

As for how to debug this, I'd say the best way would be to capture the request that the client is sending to the server.

You can do this for example by modifying the code here to point to your own server instead of airbrake's and log the requests:

https://github.com/airbrake/pybrake/blob/master/pybrake/notifier.py#L41

Or capture the HTTP traffic somehow.

You'll probably see a JSON/XML/HTTP Form Data in which there will be a "None" value attached to a property that should instead be a number, which would then raise this error server-side.

Comment: The problem ended up being that the `AIRBRAKE` setting was incorrectly configured. I was getting the `project_id` from an environment variable using `os.getenv()`, but I had mistyped the name of the environment variable, so this was ending up to be `None`. This gets interpolated straight into the `Notifier`'s `self._airbrake_url`, which ended up being `https://api.airbrake.io/api/v3/projects/None/notices` instead of the containing the 6-digit project ID. Airbrake's Go backend presumably attempts to parse the `project_id` out of the URL, which led to this error.